# Mapping disk number to Cluster Resource in windows server through power shell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

How do I map the disk number with volume in windows powershell script.?

1. `get-disk` command results in:

   ```
   disk_number friendly_name serial_number  etc..
   ```
2. `get-volume` commands results in:

   ```
   drive_letter friendly_name fstype drivetype etc..
   ```

Question 1. Before bringing up volume as a drive letter / mount point name, how do I know if I am working on the right disk?

Question 2. In cluster failover networks, If I have a disk of 10 GB and is made online, Windows automatically assigns Cluster resource name as "Cluster Disk X" when I do Get-ClusterAvaialableResource. Now how do I map the Cluster resource to the disk number?

With the below cmdlets, I find no property/parameter in common.

a)Get-ClusterResource "Cluster Disk X" |Format-List -Property *

b)Get-Disk -Number "Y" |Format-List -Property *

The situation is little twisted, when I have the disks as mount points under Drive Letter Z:

I am more interested in finding solution to Question2).
Need some pointers. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't assume there is a simple mapping between volume and disk. One disk can contain several volumes, and one volume can also span several disks.

Comment: Okay, Is there a powershell cmdlet that outputs mapped volumes if disk number is specified ?
What is the common parameter among these 2 commands ?

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/match-physical-drives-to-volume-labels-with-powershell/